# Community detection in Python

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx

I have to detection communities in network. But I need to inform the number of communities (k).

I tried this

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
cl.as_clustering().membership

# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
#  2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

However, I want to inform the number of communities

Eq.:

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
k = 2 # --> Number of communities
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy(k) # --> Note the k
```

How I do it? Are there some algorithm for that? I can to use 'Networkx' or 'igraph'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method returns a complete dendrogram, so you can have any number of communities you want. By default `as_clustering()` returns the optimal number of communities in terms of the modularity measure, but you can supply the desired number of communities.

See the documentation at the igraph homepage: http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.clustering.VertexDendrogram-class.html#as_clustering

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
k=2
cl.as_clustering(k).membership
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
#  0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```